# Upload a project to an existing one

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I have a project in azure (https://dev.azure.com/), I did it on one computer, then I started doing it on another computer and now it has no connection to the old repository, how can I push the project now in the old repository in which there are still old files? I have two repositories front and back there and on my computer

[image]

I can’t find such lines there

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/kepamuk/asdasdas.git
git push -u origin master
```

What should I do to upload my code to the old repository?

Comment: Those lines for CLI use of Git.

Comment: Hi friend, just checking in to make sure if the issue is resolved or not. If the issue persists to block you please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

> I can’t find such lines there
>
> git remote add origin https://github.com/kepamuk/asdasdas.git
>
> git push -u origin master
>
> What should I do to upload my code to the old repository?

For azure devops repos, the corresponding url is the url of your repos page in azure devops web portal.

[image]

The url format is: `https://dev.azure.com/YourOrgName/YourProjectName/_git/YourReposName`

So the corresponding commands are (check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line#create-a-new-repo)):

```
git remote add origin https://dev.azure.com/YourOrgName/YourProjectName/_git/YourReposName

git add .

git commit -m "My test commit"

git push -u origin master
```

**Note:** If you want to clone the remote repos, the url is different from the one above. Check [Clone the repo to your computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/code-with-git?view=azure-devops#clone-the-repo-to-your-computer). And you don't need to run `git remote add origin` if you run the `git clone` just now.